# Query to Display Folder of the measure

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to select a display folder of a measure (folder that I can see in the Excel Pivot Table under the measure group, under which a measure is displayed).

I tried with something like this:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[FOLDER_NAME] AS [Measures].[Amount].Properties('DISPLAY_FOLDER')
SELECT
    [Measures].[FOLDER_NAME] On 0
FROM
    MyCube
```

But I am getting an error: #Error Query The DISPLAY_FOLDER dimension attribute was not found. Maybe name of the property doesn't go like this or am I missing something else?

Because when I try with some other property like NAME instead of DISPLAY_FOLDER I am getting correct result - the name of the measure:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[MEASURE_NAME] AS [Measures].[Amount].Properties('NAME')
SELECT
    [Measures].[MEASURE_NAME] On 0
FROM
    MyCube
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think folder name is accessible in this way. However you can use Dmv's to solve your issue.

```
select * from $System.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
```

In the result check the MEASUREGROUP_NAME

Comment: Thanks, and is there any way to do it with a pure MDX, like I tried above? Because I see that DisplayFolder measure property is listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/configure-measure-properties?view=sql-server-2017 , but I do not understand why I cannot access it.

Comment: This property is not exposed in the way you are accessing it.